# Temporarily switch off mixed tabs and spaces check at runtime

Tags: python, cpython

Is there a way how to switch off (and on later) this check at runtime?

The motivation is that I need to use third party libraries which do not care about tabs and spaces mixing and thus running my code with [`-t` switch](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-t) issues warnings.

(I hope that analogous method can be used for the `-b` switch.)

**edit:** I forgot to note, that the library already mixes tabs and spaces in one file and that's why I see the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The limitation is only within a module. It's perfectly OK to mix modules with tab indentation and those with space indentation inside the same project.

I can't think of a situation where you'd ever want to mix tabs and spaces in the same file and therefore wouldn't want to check for it.

Comment: I apologize, I had to say that the library already mixes tabs and spaces in one file and that's why I see the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a runtime switch like you describe, but converting a library from mixed to spaces-only isn't hard, if you have a copy you can edit:
In the shell:

```
touch temp.py; for x in $(find /path/to/library/ -name '*.py' -print); do expand -it 4 $x > temp.tmp; cat temp.tmp > $x; done; rm temp.tmp
```

Replace `/path/to/library/` with the path you your library files directory.

Personally, I prefer tabs to spaces, but this will prevent the warnings and shouldn't have many unforeseen consequences. One consequence you should be aware of is that **leading tabs in multi-line string literals will also be converted to spaces**.

Converting from mixed or spaces to tabs is also possible, like with the `unexpand` program. However, conversion from spaces/mixed to tabs is much harder and more error prone, since spaces are syntactically ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, it's possible solution, but I would have to convert the library every time I upgrade it.

Comment: @RadekHolý: Have you tried to report the bug upstream?